# how install libvips NetVips in Azure cloud - Error:Unable to load DLL \ 'libvips-42.dll\ ' or one of its dependencies

Tags: azure, azure-function-app, vips

I can run an azure function app with libvips library from localhost for this function app - manipulation for images output correctly. I setup my local environment by saving [libvips win64](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases) in a folder in my windows 10 PC, added libvips bin folder to environment PATH and in Visual studio I installed nuget NetVips, NetVips.Native.win-64.

This is the method I run :

```
var rgbThumbnail = NetVips.Image.ThumbnailBuffer(thisRGBImgBytes, 256);
```

I'm trying to run the .Net Core 3.1 V3 function app from azure. When I run from cloud I get "Error:Unable to load DLL \ 'libvips-42.dll\ ' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found . (0x8007007E)"

I had expected for the nuget packages in VS to suffice when uploading to the function app in azure. I've looked on the internet how to install libvips in Azure but I can't find any reference. Can someone please help?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problems.
Libvips is using more then one dll.

Download from
https://libvips.github.io/libvips/

Add all dll's then remove one by one.
Or directly identify the missing dll.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, right-click your **Azure Functions project**, then click on **Manage NuGet Packages**, and install the following packages:

- **NetVips** (latest version)
- **NetVips.Native** (latest version)

That should solve the issue related to missing DLLs.